# Multiply each elements in Array with different values? Code not working

Tags: javascript

The function is supposed to add the change in my pocket and it checks to see if i can afford the price, the array will always be represented in the following order: quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies. In the following example it says "false", when it should say true. please help :

```
console.log(changeEnough([30, 40, 20, 5], 12.55));

function changeEnough(change, price) {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < change.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            total += change[i] * 0.25;
        } else if (i === 1) {
            total += change[i] * 0.10;
        } else if (i === 2) {
            total += change[i] * 0.05;
        } else {
            total += change[i] * 0.01;
        }
    }

    return total > price;
}
```

Comment: 12.55 is NOT greater than 12.55 - it's EQUAL

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop

```js
function changeEnough(change, price) {
const [quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies] = change
const total = quarters * .25 +
              dimes * .10 +
              nickels * .5 +
              pennies * .1
return total >= price
}
```

Comment: @Iamnotverysmart If this answer works for you please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

you could use map to multiply value * quantity and reduce to add them all up

```
const data = [
{name: 'quarter', value: .25, quantity: 30},
{name: 'dime', value: .1, quantity: 40},
{name: 'nickel', value: .05, quantity: 20},
{name: 'penny', value: .01, quantity: 5},
]
$( document ).ready(function() {
  changeEnough(data, 12.55);
});

function changeEnough(myarray, target){
 return data.map((x) => x.value * x.quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) >= target
}
```